# how to display result after requst in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i present my result in the ajax success, so it display the return result and do not reload the page.

This is my script ---

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home',
                type: 'post',
                data: {contentSearch: $('#contentSearch').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('table.my-data-table').dataTable({}) // the table
                     // here i want to show the result
                     // how can i show the result here
                     // i am passing the result as result in the twig file
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

in the controller i am sending the result like 'result' => $result

```
return $this->render('AdminBundle:Home:home.html.twig', array(
        'pageTitle' => 'my ajax',
        'result' => $result // result sending to twig file
            )
```

So how can i display the result through ajax, anyone knows how to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you want to replace the whole page, `$(document.body).html(data);` (for example, use selectors to replace a section) Then you can call `.dataTable` on the table.

Comment: @TylerSebastian i do not want to replace the whole page, i just want to display the results in a table or somewhere, so the whole page do not need to be replaced i guess, only the value in the table need to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action so the page doesn't reload.

```
$("#searchform").on('submit', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // ...
});
```

If you're receiving a data array containing the table data then pass it to the data property on [dataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data):

```
   success: function (data) {
     $('table.my-data-table').dataTable({
       data: data
     });
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is not working for me, how can i replace the whole page without being reload the page, i have put at the last return false in my query i guess i also do the same thing